# Sharepoint webpart 2016 and oracle db 9i

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, system.data.oracleclient

after installing odac and oracle client 12.2 ,i test the oracle connection via visual studio 2015 using system.data.oracleClient,my oracle db version is 9i, the connection working fine at visual studio 2015 
, but when i deploy it as Webpart to sharepoint 2016 its make an error
while its work fine as webpart in sharepoint2010. the problem just in sharepoint2016, i use .net framework 4.5

i dont understand how its working at visualstudio  while not working in sharepoint 2016 the error is Error=ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported

Application error when access **mypage here**, Error=ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.    at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)

Comment: i would guess that as oracle 9i has been out of support for 8 years that SP has decided not to support it from version 2016

Comment: so,what the solution now,

Comment: create webservice at another server to reterive data and use it at sp 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Client 12.2 can not connect to Oracle 9i, only 11.2 client can connect to 9.2.0.
[Client/Server Interoperability Support [ID 207303.1]](https://82star.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/clientserver-interoperability-support-id-207303-1/)

Comment: but how its working at visual studio, if i build web application and put the connection and simple query. its working fine!!!